# iReport pie chart with limits label does not format other slice

Tags: formatting, label, ireport, pie-chart

I am working on iReport.  I have a pie chart which I have limited to 5 slices. I then needed to format the results so I created a variable: new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0").format($F{Service}).  The issue is the "other" slice which is a total of remaining numbers.  If I format the labels the other slice does not show.  If I add this format formula into the ChartDetails/OtherSectionValue/OtherLabelExpression I get a formatted number that represents just one number from the total - not a total.  If I do not format the label all numbers show.  Is there a way I can get the format yet still allow the other slice to add properly.

Thanks for any help.

Sherry

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out, I was certainly making it more difficult that necessary.  Just made it into an integer and used ${1} in the label format.